# python urllib.request http error 403: forbidden

Tags: python, urllib

```py
import urllib.request
url = "https://wallpapercrafter.com/desktop7/1788714-Anime-InuYasha-Kagome-Higurashi-1080P.jpg"
try:
  urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
  urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"user-agent": "mozilla/5.0"}))
```

I'm getting the same error code twice. I need it to work so I can download the file. please help

Comment: The server decided it doesn't want to talk to you.  Why?  Perhaps it doesn't like the country that your IP address is located in, or you've made too many requests recently, or it's expecting some header value on the request, or it thinks you're a robot... There's no way to tell exactly why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific site in question, wallpapercrafter.com, is protected by cloudflare which will block web scrapers. Even if you do send valid headers, cloudflare will simple block you from letting your request reach the origin server. However, if you are determined to do so, I would recommend this python module: https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper